# C# Casting MemoryStream to FileStream

Tags: c#, stream, filestream, memorystream

My code is this:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(someText);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
FileStream file = (FileStream)reader.BaseStream;
```

Later I'm using file.Name.

I'm getting an InvalidCastException: it displays follows

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' to type 'System.IO.FileStream'.

I read somewhere that I should just change FileStream to Stream. Is there something else I should do?

Comment: This approach is wrong. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. A `MemoryStream` can definitely not be cast to a `FileStream`, and while you can cast to `Stream`, that class doesn't have a `.Name` property. What is it that you're trying to do? Which name are you after?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A `MemoryStream` is not associated with a file, and has no concept of a filename. Basically, you can't do that.

You certainly can't cast between them; you can only cast upwards an downwards - not sideways; to visualise:

```
        Stream
          |
   ---------------
   |             |
FileStream    MemoryStream
```

You can cast a `MemoryStream` to a `Stream` trivially, and a `Stream` to a `MemoryStream` via a type-check; but never a `FileStream` to a `MemoryStream`. That is like saying a dog is an animal, and an elephant is an animal, so we can cast a dog to an elephant.

You *could* subclass `MemoryStream` and add a `Name` property (that you supply a value for), but there would still be no commonality between a `FileStream` and a `YourCustomMemoryStream`, and `FileStream` doesn't implement a pre-existing interface to get a `Name`; so the caller would have to **explicitly** handle both separately, or use duck-typing (maybe via `dynamic` or reflection).

Another option (perhaps easier) might be: write your data to a temporary file; use a `FileStream` from there; then (later) delete the file.

Answer (score 5):

You can compare `Stream` with animal, `MemoryStream` with dog and `FileStream` with cat. Although a dog is an animal, and a cat is an animal, a dog certainly is not a cat.

If you want to copy data from one stream to another, you will need to create both streams, read from one and write to the other.

Answer (score 3):

This operation is not possible. Both `FileStream` and `MemoryStream` are directly derived from `Stream`, so they are sibling types. In general, in the following scenario:

```
 public class A { }
 public class B : A { }
 public class C : A { }
```

It is not possible to cast B to C or vice-versa. There is no "is-a" relationship between B and C.