# Is it possible to set properties on a returned object from Moq?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, moq

I have the following method

```
    public void ValidateAccessToFile(string filePath, List<String> errorMessageList)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = (FileStream)_iomgr.OpenFile(filePath))
            {
                if (fs.CanRead && fs.CanWrite) { }
                else
                {
                    errorMessageList.Add("Can not read/write to the specified file.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorMessageList.Add(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

and id like to test that it writes to the "errorMessageList" if either of the properties, CanRead or CanWrite are false. Is this possible?

```
    [Test]
    public void ValidateAccessToFile_CanReadWriteToFile_NoErrorAddedToErrorListMessage()
    {
        Mock<IIOManager> mock = new Mock<IIOManager>();
        mock.Setup(x => x.OpenFile(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new MemoryStream());

        List<String> errorMessageList = new List<string>();

        VerificationManager testObject = new VerificationManager(mock.Object);
        testObject.ValidateAccessToFile("Random.txt", errorMessageList);
        Assert.AreEqual(errorMessageList.Count, 0);
    }
```

How can i assign a value to the New MemoryStream properties?
Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

Below is the final test method i wrote.

```
    public void ValidateAccessToFile_CanReadWriteToFile_NoErrorAddedToErrorListMessage()
    {
        bool _isReadOnly = true;
        List<String> errorMessageList = new List<string>();

        Mock<IIOManager> mock = new Mock<IIOManager>();
        mock
            .Setup(x => x.IsReadOnly(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(_isReadOnly);

        VerificationManager testObject = new VerificationManager(mock.Object);
        testObject.ValidateAccessToFile(It.IsAny<string>(), errorMessageList);
        Assert.AreEqual(errorMessageList.Count, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.canread.aspx) for `MemoryStream.CanRead`, the property will always return `true` as long as the stream is open.  (`CanWrite` is less clear, but I believe it is the same.)

So, you can close the stream before returning it, or you can mock a `Stream` with the appropriate overrides.

Incidentally, I'm not sure that a `MemoryStream` can be casted into a `FileStream`.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8297613/1210520).

Comment: I finally went with a different solution which relied upon using the IsReadOnly property. Steve is correct about not being able to cast between MemoryStream and FileStream which was one of the reasons which i reengineered the method. See edit to original question. (Thanks again Steve)

Answer (score 4):

Just don't return a `MemoryStream`, but a properly configured mock of a `MemoryStream`.

```
var m = new Mock<MemoryStream>();
m.Setup(x=>x.CanRead).Returns(false);
m.Setup(x=>x.CanWrite).Returns(false);
mock.Setup(x => x.OpenFile(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(m.Object);
```

Comment: there is cast to `FileStream`, will this Mock<MemoryStream> be casted to it

Comment: I tried setting it up to return a mock as u suggested but it didnt work. Im going to try removing the casts and see if it will then work

Comment: In this method, is there any need to use a `FileStream` instead of just a `Stream`?

Comment: Im not sure. Im using it to check a specified file can be read/written to. Regarding your code above. Does this mean i could change the OpenFile method to just return a FileStream and then directly mock that as u have done with var m = ... What happens when the returned type get used in the assignment to fs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 public class BadFileStream : FileStream
        {
            public BadFileStream(string path, FileMode mode) : base(path, mode)
            {
            }

            public override bool CanWrite
            {
                get
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            public override bool CanRead
            {
                get
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

and change mock

```
mock.Setup(x => x.OpenFile(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new BadFileStream(file, FileMode.Open));
```